# Sending Array of string in grape API

Tags: ruby, ruby-grape, grape-api

Using grape api, I try to send an array of string but I always have the response `error, codes is not valid`

In my model, I expose my field like this :

```
expose :code, documentation: { type: Array[String]}
```

And when I make my test, I pass

```
"code": [
      "037ffdb5-6901-404c-b152-8321a32aa397", "1762005c-8cf0-427d-b090-d354d6255eba"
    ],
```

When I check in my console, I have an array of string passed in my params :

```
=> ["037ffdb5-6901-404c-b152-8321a32aa397", "1762005c-8cf0-427d-b090-d354d6255eba"]
```

Is anyone having a clue why my params are not valid ?

Comment: Are you sure this is a Grape validation error? If you have the correct params inside your controller, Grape didn't reject the request.

Comment: Just glancing at [the documentation](https://github.com/ruby-grape/grape-entity/blob/master/README.md), and comparing it to your code, it seems odd that you're defining the field type only in the **documentation**, but not as an actual type? I.e. you should be doing something more along the lines of `expose :code, type: Array[String], documentation: { type: 'A list of strings'}`? Not 100% sure if that's valid, but you aught to check the documentation first.